# Modern looking visualization of folder structure

Tags: linux

Is there a tool for nice, modern looking visualization of folder (with cloned GIT repository) structure in Linux? I know there is command `tree` but it outputs "ugly", text based results. What I'm looking for is some JPG/PNG/... looking result, possibly in chart form.

EDIT: Just found [treeviz](http://www.randelshofer.ch/treeviz/) it is good but I would prefer something more "traditional" :)

EDIT2: Sample what it be perfect ouptut [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F7Vj.jpg)

[image: desired diagram]

Thanks

Comment: So do you want traditional or modern?

Comment: fair enough... Something like this http://imgur.com/eDke5

Comment: I thought there was something like that on the page. There's something called theJIT (javascript info visualizer thing) that has exactly that and calls it spacetree, it's a good place to start searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual answer for this sort of requirement is to have a script generate a graph description that you feed to something like [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) or [aisee](http://www.absint.com/aisee/index.htm)

[For example](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7275?page=0,2)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Gource](http://gource.io/) produces very sleek file structure visualization of VCS. It produces video, but you can speed it up using + and take a screenshot using F12.

[image: gource]